# how to make a graph of equipotential curves from two point charges

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm attempting to make a graph of the equipotential curves of two point charges while showing the electric field lines. I can do the electric field lines but the equipotentials are giving me trouble.

My sample for one point charge was:

```
equipots1 = ContourPlot[
              V1plot, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
              ContourShading -> None, Contours -> 10, AspectRatio -> ar,
              ImageSize -> Small, ContourStyle -> {{Purple, Opacity[0.6]}}
            ]
```

Comment: What's the formula for the potential for one point source? Two? (Remember about superposition.) Once you have that, with an appropriate substitution for $r$, you can just plug it into `ContourPlot`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider two charges, `Q1` and `Q2`, centered at positions, `pos1` and `pos2`, respectively.

```
k = 9*10^9;
```

Then, you can write a function which takes `Q1`, `Q2`, `pos1`, `pos2`, and an equivalent `r` as arguments.

```
plotEquipotential[Q1_, Q2_, pos1_, pos2_, r_] := 
 ContourPlot[
  k Q1/Norm[{x, y} - pos1] + k Q2/Norm[{x, y} - pos2] == k/r, 
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}
 ]
```

Example plot:

```
plotEquipotential[1, 2, {0,0}, {0,3}, 1]
```

[image]

To create a `gif`:

```
Export["equipotentialPlot.gif", 
 plotEquipotential[1, 2, {0, 0}, {0, 3}, #] & /@ Range[0.1, 2, 0.1], 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 0.2]
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of crafting your own `norm` function, `Norm` does it all for you.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank you.